# Package jruby script as .jar with annotations

Tags: java, jar, jruby

Is there a way to package a jruby script as a .jar file with support for annotations? I don't think [warbler](https://github.com/jruby/warbler) does this. [jruby2java](https://kenai.com/projects/ruby2java) looks like it supported annotations but it hasn't been updated in four years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JRuby compiler](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JRubyCompiler), which is part of the core JRuby features, has the `java_annotation` method that allows you to define annotations in your JRuby code.

Here is an example with Spring MVC annotations, where annotations are added on the class `GreetingController`, and on the `print` method:

```
java_import 'org.springframework.stereotype.Controller'
java_import 'org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping'
java_import 'org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod'
java_import 'org.springframework.ui.ModelMap'

java_package 'com.weblogism.myapp'
java_annotation 'Controller'
java_annotation 'RequestMapping("/welcome")'
class GreetingController

  java_annotation 'RequestMapping'
  java_signature 'String print(ModelMap model)'
  def print(model)
    model.add_attribute('greeting', 'Hello, World!')
    "index"
  end
end
```

(The full example can be found on [github](https://github.com/tychobrailleur/jruby-springmvc); the JRuby compiler is called by the `jruby-maven-plugin`)